# How Can OSGI and JSF work together?

Tags: jsf, osgi, bundle, bndtools, wab

I'm new in OSGI and I'm having many problems to try to create WABs. I'm using BndTools with Eclipse to help me with OSGi. My problem now is how can I integrate JSF with OSGi. I want to make one main web server, and add bundles with jsf pages runtime. How can I do this? What are the needs?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

JSF is quite complex due to it's classloading mechanism. If you use [Pax-Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) you are able to use JSF, though it requires some special handling. For more details get in contact with the [OPS4j community](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/ops4j). 
Another hint, since you seem to try to build your own "web-container", I don't recommend that, try to use an existing one, makes life easier :)